# Reset background opacity on key press input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

When someone clicks on an input field, the background of the site gets an opacity to emphasize on the input field. That's very cool, but I would want that solely when clicked on the input field and not when typing something in the input field.

So what I would want to achieve, is to **reset the opacity to 1 when someone is actually typing (key press) in the input field**.

Is this possible? If so, how should I achieve this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="blur"> </div>
<input class="blurOnFocus">
```

**CSS:**

```
.blurry {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function onFocus() {
    var blurElements = document.getElementsByClassName('blur');
    for (var i = 0, l = blurElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        blurElements[i].classList.add("blurry");
    }
}

function onFocusOut() {
    var blurElements = document.getElementsByClassName('blur');
    for (var i = 0, l = blurElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        blurElements[i].classList.remove("blurry");
    }
}
```

Comment: whats your `.blur` classes opacity? it may be overriden

Comment: The .blur class gets overruled by .blurry... so .blur becomes .blurry which has 0.5 opacity. What I want now, is that .blurry becomes 1 only if someone is typing in the input field...

Comment: What events are you binding onfocus and onFocusOut to?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function changebg() { 
  var maindivclass = document.getElementById("maindiv").classList; 
  maindivclass.remove("red"); 
    maindivclass.add("blue");
}
```

```css
 .blue{background:blue;}
 .red{background: red;}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li id="my_block1">  
  <span>some text 1</span>         
  <div class="form-group">
   <input id="input1" type="text" name="my_item_1" onkeypress="changebg()">
      <div class="red" id="maindiv">test</div>
  </div>
 </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: My dear friend, did you even try my code? I am blurring the whole background EXCEPT the input field... so I don't want the background of the input field to be changed, but the background of the other elements. Please try my code first.

Comment: I have added what you want using class name.

Comment: Thanks, yet still not what I am trying to do. I want it with my code snippet / example, not an entirely new one. Thanks for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `keydown` event on the input field to remove the `.blurry` class which you applied on `focus`.

```js
function onFocus() {
    var blurElements = document.getElementsByClassName('blur');
    for (var i = 0, l = blurElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        blurElements[i].classList.add("blurry");
    }
}

function onKeydown() {
    var blurElements = document.getElementsByClassName('blur');
    for (var i = 0, l = blurElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        blurElements[i].classList.remove("blurry");
    }
}

var el = document.getElementsByClassName("blurOnFocus");
for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
 el[i].addEventListener( 'focus', onFocus );
 el[i].addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeydown );
 el[i].addEventListener( 'blur', onKeydown );
}
```

```css
.blurOnFocus {
margin: 30px;
}
.blur {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.blurry{
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
<input class="blurOnFocus" />
<input class="blurOnFocus" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Lavish, thanks for your answer. Could you give an example with my code so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: It's not working man. It says this: Uncaught ReferenceError: onFocus is not defined and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Also: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Thanks. I can see it works on your snippet, but for me it keeps saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. What do you think the problem could be?

Comment: maybe it's because of the class you are useing. I am using `blurOnInput` class. I have updated it for two inputs. Check now

Comment: We are close! Now, I only have this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: onFocusOut is not defined. Just using a different classname, but that's normal. The blur works, but on key press, the blur is not going away as in your example.

Comment: are you defining `onFocusOut` somewhere? You are mostly attaching onFocusOut somewhere but not defining it. And that's why it is giving this error.

Comment: I have attached onKeydown function to both events. Because same thing needs to be executed on both events.

Comment: Thanks. I have this input field HTML: <input class="blurOnFocus">. That's all I am doing right now. I am using your code, but it is not blurring anymore... not working man.

Comment: Need to see your code to help more. can you inspect and see if blurry class is getting attached to the element? Also if you see I have put inputs inside div with `blur` class so that blur effect comes around input.

Comment: Nope, blurry class is not being added. Yeah, I have the blur too. My own snippet worked, so I know how to do that, but right now, with your code, the blurry class is not being attached. So it's not blurring at all.

Comment: can you update your post with latest code. So that I get clear picture of what is missing?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my HTML. To sum up: I am using YOUR CSS, YOUR HTML and YOUR JS. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with `onclick` & `onkeypress` events to detect conditions; and for changing CSS class you'd better use `setAttribute` function.

Assuming this is your HTML snippet:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="blur"> Lorem ipsum... </div>
<input type="text" name="myInp" id="myInp" />
```

The script below does what you need:

```
document.getElementById('myInp').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('myDiv').setAttribute('class', 'blurry');
};
document.getElementById('myInp').onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('myDiv').setAttribute('class', 'blur');
};
```

---

### Edited: Works with pure classes & tags

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var j=0; j<inputs.length ; j++) {
    inputs[j].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var blurredItems = document.getElementsByClassName('blur');
        for (var i = 0; i < blurredItems.length; i++) {
            blurredItems[i].setAttribute('class', 'blurry');
        }
    });
    inputs[j].addEventListener('keypress', function () {
        var blurriedItems = document.getElementsByClassName('blurry');
        for (var i = 0; i < blurriedItems.length; i++) {
            blurriedItems[i].setAttribute('class', 'blur');
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but it uses ID's! I am not using ID's, because I have multiple input fields. Could you change it to my example please? I am using classes.

Comment: Sure. on which of them? how do you detect input? you mean any input though?

Comment: Please see my updated post. I have added the input field HTML. I want this to any input field I give the functions too. So no ID's, classes.

Comment: @Siyah Updated. You need only section below **Edited**

Comment: Nope man. Not working at all. Uncaught ReferenceError: onFocus is not defined. It's not even blurring anymore.

Comment: @Siyah you need to remove `onfocus="onFocus()" onfocusout="onFocusOut()"` from your input elements. You don't need them anymore.

Comment: Yes, okay, I did, yet it's still not working. No errors in the console, but nothing happens when I click on the input field. No blur: nothing at all.